# Notation: Precedence in multiple levels of exponentiation

Tags: notation, exponentiation

When people write $a^{b^c}$, does it refer to $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$  or $a^{(b^c)}$? What about the notation a^b^c (without superscripts)?

Is there an agreed-upon convention?